# How to compute the indefinite integrate of n-th tetration of x?

Tags: calculus, integration, tetration, hyperoperation

How can the following indefinite integral be computed ?

$ \int{x↑↑n} dx $

where $n$ = {$x$ $\in$ $N^+$ : ${x > 2}$}

Here ${x↑↑n}$ refers to $n$th tetration of $x$. I tried searching over the internet to find a general formulae for calculating it when the value of  $n$ varies and came across a single paper which had an application of W-Lambart function.

Is there any other method to compute it ?

Comment: Here ${x↑↑n}$ = $x[4]n$

Comment: Chances of a closed-form solution are negative, I am afraid.

Comment: Can you do even $\int x^x\;dx$ in closed form?  I can't.  There is no reason to think $x^{x^x}$ or $x^{x^{x^x}}$ are any easier.

Comment: @GEdgar: $\int x^x dx$ =
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^{i+1}}\frac{Γ(i+1, ln(x^{-i}))}{i!\cdot i^i}$$

Comment: I forgot to mention $+C$

Comment: I think $\sum_0^\infty$ should not be considered closed form.

Comment: Well, i actually need a generalised formulae for calculating it in the the form of an infinite series. Does it exists ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution expressed on the form of series isn't generally accepted as a closed form.  However, the choice of what to call closed-form and what not is rather arbitrary. In common sens, a closed form is a combination of a $\underline{\text{finite}}$ number of $\underline{\text{standard}}$ functions.

Then the question is what is a standard function ? When a function (defined by an infinite series or by an integral or by other means) becomes a standard function ?

For an example related to $ \int{x↑↑n} dx $ in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function the function named Sphd covers a lot of cases.
$$\text{Sphd}(\alpha,x)=\int_0^x t^{\alpha t}dt$$
generalized with :

[image]

$$ \int_0^x{x↑↑n} \: dx = \text{Sphd}_{n}(1,...;x)\qquad \text{Eq.}(12:5)$$

And from Eq.$(12:6)$
$$ \int_a^b{x↑↑\infty} \: dx =\text{Sphd}_{\infty}(1,...;b)-\text{Sphd}_{\infty}(1,...;a)=-\int_a^b\frac{\text{W}(-\ln(t))}{\ln(t)}dt$$
W is the Lambert W function.

Of course, all this is purely formal since Sphd isn't a standardized special function. 
Creating symbols for new functions may appear as vicious circle. A discussion about the definition of new special functions, standardization of such functions and further use can be found in :  https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales .

Answer (score 2):

There are easy taylor series for $(x+1)$, $(x+1)^{(x+1)}$, $(x+1)^{(x+1)^{(x+1)}}$, and so on. For them you can do formal integration by integrating the series-terms. (Whether this gives series with nonzero convergence-radius  or not, and something else, I don't know at the moment). A general formula for the generating of the coefficients, which would be simpler than the explicite computation by the taylor-series expansion for some given tetration-height, I don't see at the moment. But the remarkable pattern of the coefficients when iterating to higher $n$ has been discussed many times.

---

added: you might be interested in this essay on "[tetrating the pascal-matrix](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/PascalMatrixTetrated.pdf)" which gives in chap 2 possibly helpful discussion of concept and pattern, although it may as well be some overkill for your question...

---

Example: first few taylor-coefficients for $1$, $x+1$, $(x+1)^{(x+1)}$ , ...

```
  1  x  x^2 x^3  x^4   x^5    x^6     x^7
  ---------------------------------------------------------------
  1  0  0    0    0     0       0         0      for f0(x)=1
  1  1  0    0    0     0       0         0      for f1(x)=(x+1)^f0(x)
  1  1  1  1/2  1/3  1/12    3/40    -1/120      for f2(x)=(x+1)^f1(x)
  1  1  1  3/2  4/3   3/2   53/40   233/180
  1  1  1  3/2  7/3     3  163/40  1861/360
  1  1  1  3/2  7/3     4  243/40  3421/360
  1  1  1  3/2  7/3     4  283/40  4321/360
  1  1  1  3/2  7/3     4  283/40  4681/360
  1  1  1  3/2  7/3     4  283/40  4681/360
```

The columnwise progressions may be illustrated by the moving differences:

```
  1  x  x^2 x^3  x^4   x^5    x^6     x^7    for
  ---------------------------------------------------------------
  1  0  0    0    0      0     0        0
  .  1  0    0    0      0     0        0    (x+1)-1
  .  .  1  1/2  1/3   1/12  3/40   -1/120    (x+1)^(x+1)-(x+1)
  .  .  .    1    1  17/12   5/4  469/360    (x+1)^(x+1)^(x+1)-(x+1)^(x+1)
  .  .  .    .    1    3/2  11/4     31/8
  .  .  .    .    .      1     2     13/3
  .  .  .    .    .      .     1      5/2
  .  .  .    .    .      .     .        1
  .  .  .    .    .      .     .        0
```

If we scale the coefficients by factorials (columnwise) we find the limit of the sequence of rows in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A136461) and they can also be found when having the expansion of the LambertW-function for power series at hand:

```
      exp(-lambertw(-log(1+x)))-1    \\ Pari/GP gives the limiting set of  
                                     \\ coefficients for the infinite iteration height 
      %20 = x + x^2 + 3/2*x^3 + 7/3*x^4 + 4*x^5 + 283/40*x^6 + 4681/360*x^7 + O(x^8)
```

After that, you can write your integrals by the formal integration-rule for coefficients of the taylor-series.

Comment: That means the final result can be obtained by observing the pattern ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But I've never found out a "simple" pattern-formula with a meaningful/obvious option to interpolate to fractional iteration-heights.

Comment: Does a solution to this indefinite integral exists or has someone ever tried to compute it ?

Comment: @AdityaRaj - what do you mean "solution"? You only need adapt the coefficients and exponents of the $x$ in the series for getting the series for integrals. You can do it yourself, no further big plan is needed...Perhaps Wolfram alpha gives even the integral for the $\exp(...)$-expression, just type it into it....

Comment: Well Wolframe Alpha fails to provide the indefinite integral of nth tetration of x. Even i have tried every online integral calculator over the internet.

Comment: Well Wolframe Alpha fails to provide the indefinite integral of nth tetration of x. Even i have tried every online integral calculator over the internet.

Comment: @AdityaRaj - have you tried `integrate [(1+x)^(1+x)]` or similar for the other iterates? At least W|A was able to give the leading terms of the power series for  such expression last time when I tried...  Otherwise you could install Pari/GP or use the online-software "sage" (don't have the link at hand).

Answer (score 1):

Your can try to compute it approximately.
As an example. If you have the integral.
$$
I_2(a)=\int_1^a x^{x^x} dx\,,
$$ with $a\gg1$. In fact this faction grows very rapidly, it will be works for a=3, with enough good accuracy.
We can represent this integral in the following form
$
I_2(a)=\int_1^a e^{S(x)} dx
$
and do the integration by parts
$$
I(a)=\int_1^a e^{S(x)} dx=\int_1^a \frac{de^{S(x)}}{S'(x)} dx=\frac{S(a)}{S'(a)}-\frac{S(1)}{S'(1)}-\int_1^a dxe^{S(x)} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{S'(x)}. 
$$
The main contribution is given by the term $\frac{S(a)}{S'(a)}$, the integral term is a the next correction. You can continue to do the integration by part to improve your accuracy.
In such case 
$I_2(a)=\dfrac{a^{a^a}}{a^a(1/a+\ln a(\ln a+1 ))}$
The I_2(3)=$1,07 *10^{11}$, the result by numerical integration is $1,11*10^{11}$.

In fact this asymptotics depends only on upper limit of integration.

In the general case, using the notation presented above we have
$$
I_n(a)=\int_0^a{x↑↑n} dx=\frac{x↑↑n}{d/dx({x↑↑(n-1)} \ln(x))}|_{x=a}
$$